# Firebase dynamic link - 403 error (you don't have access to this page)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

I am setting up firebase dynamic links for our Angular/Ionic app for the Android platform. I've already configured all the settings and started testing.

For some links, it works as expected (it opens the application and redirects a user to the correct page).  However, for another one it says `403` error - you don't have access to this page. Please check screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Jmc.jpg.

Here is an example of dynamic link - `https://{subdomain}.page.link/?link={appLink}&apn={appPackage}&amv={appVersion}&afl={appLink}`

Do you have any idea what could cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a URl encoding problem in the link field, try encoding your url (only the link value, not the entire FDL)

Something like:

```
https://{subdomain}.page.link/?link={encodeAppLink}&apn={appPackage}&amv={appVersion}&afl={appLink}
```